# Exponential identity ${(x^a)}^b=x^{ab}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, eulers-number-e

We all know that $e^{\pi i}=\cos \pi + i \sin \pi=-1$, and that ${(x^a)}^b=x^{a \times b}$, also $e^{2 \pi i}=\cos {2\pi} + i \sin {2\pi}=1$.

Here's my problem, we have $a \in \mathbb R$, and I want to find value (or set of possible values) of $e^{2a\pi i}$, so I followed these steps:  $$e^{2a\pi i}={(e^{2 \pi i})}^a=1^a=1$$
By using the exponential identity ${(x^a)}^b=x^{ab}$ and knowing that $1^x=1:x \in \mathbb C$, I ended up with $100$% possibility that $e^{2a\pi i}=1$, **But** by following different steps I got something else:
$$e^{2a\pi i}={(e^{\pi i})}^{2a}=(-1)^{2a}$$
And I ended up with two possibilities: $$\text{if} \ a \in \mathbb Z 
\implies (-1)^{2a}=1 \\ \text{if} \ a \notin \mathbb Z 
\implies (-1)^{2a} \ne 1$$

So, I suppose there's something wrong in my steps, even after checking all the laws and identities used my steps seemed to be right, so if you you caught the mistake or have an explanation **please write it down below** because this problem is driving me crazy !

**Note:** I tried using Wolframalpha and Geogebra to check if this rule apply to complex numbers, and I got the same result for $(e^i)^\pi=(e^\pi)^i$. Also I'm seeking a deductive proof, references are preferred to be mentioned.

Comment: The exponential rule, $(a^b)^c= a^{bc}$, true for **real numbers**, does not extend to complex numbers.

Comment: Additionally, depending on how you define complex exponentiation, $(a^b)^c$ and $(a^c)^b$ may be unequal.  Try $a=-1$, $b=2$, and $c=\frac{1}{3}$ using the following definition for $z\mapsto z^{\frac13}$: if $z=r\exp(\text{i}\theta)$ with  $r\geq 0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, then $$z^{\frac13}:=\sqrt[3]{r}\,\exp\left(\frac{\text{i}\theta}{3}\right)\,.$$  Only one of these values equals $a^{bc}$, if we define $$z^{\frac23}:=\sqrt[3]{r^2}\,\exp\left(\frac{2\text{i}\theta}{3}\right)$$ for $z=r\exp(\text{i}\theta)$ with  $r\geq 0$ and $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$.

Comment: Actually, this itself demonstrates a problem in defining $a^b$ for general complex numbers $a, b$.

Comment: Actually I tried using Wolframalpha and Geogebra to check if this rule apply to complex numbers, and I got the same result for $(e^i)^\pi=(e^\pi)^i$.

Comment: @anas Doing one example proves only that it works for that example. In your post there is already an example where it doesn't work.

Comment: @MattSamuel , can you please post a reference for what you say (that this rule doesn't extend to complex numbers) and thanks for reply.

Comment: $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ does not hold.

Comment: @Yves Daoust prove that please using recommendations up in the question.

Comment: @anas I added an example to my answer, but I don't have a reference other than that. If you understand the example, it shouldn't require an appeal to authority.

Comment: @anaspcpro: this question has been asked million times here under this or other forms and the invalidity of this identity is well-known. F.i. $((-1)^2)^{1/2}\ne-1$.

Comment: @Matt Samuel, I understand it well but I don't want an example, I want a proof over all complex numbers or reference. However I want to thank you for your replies.

Comment: @anas There's no proof over all complex numbers, because it does hold in some cases. The only proof that is required to show it does not hold is a single counterexample. No one is claiming that it fails in all cases.

Comment: @anaspcpro:  a single counter-example is more than enough to invalidate a theorem.

Comment: You are all claiming that but I want a proof, a proof for what you say whatever it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the identity $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$ already fails in the real numbers: Take $x=-1$, $a=2$, $b=1/2$. Then:
$$(x^a)^b = ((-1)^2)^{1/2} = 1^{1/2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$$
but
$$x^{ab} = (-1)^{2(1/2)} = (-1)^1 = -1$$
Note however that the rule *does* hold if both $a$ and $b$ are integers (and, if any of them is not positive, $x\ne 0$, as otherwise the powers are not defined at all). Moreover, with the usual definition, it also holds if $x$ is a *positive* real number.

The root of the problem (no pun intended) is that the equation $x^a=1$ in general has more than one solution, and in the complex numbers there is no choice that fulfils all desired properties.

This can be seen most easily when writing the complex number in polar form, $x = r \mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}$. Then the most obvious value for $x^a$ would be $r^a \mathrm e^{\mathrm i a\phi}$. However consider the case $a=1/2$. If $x$ goes around the origin once along the unit circle, $x^{1/2}$, starting at $1$, goes just half that circle. At the end, it ends up at the *other* root of the equation $x^2=1$, namely $-1$. Only after *another* full circle the square root returns to $1$.

But a function can only have one value. Therefore we have to make a choice. In the real numbers that's unproblematic, as we only have square roots of positive numbers, and thus it's no problem to just use the root positive. But in the complex numbers, as seen above, we can continuously move the root from one solution to another. Thus we have no choice but to add some discontinuity, called a Riemann cut.

The most common choice it to make the cut right below the negative real line. That is, we choose the angle of the polar coordinates of $x$ *before* applying the exponential to be in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Now let's look at your example:

To calculate $\mathrm (e^{2\pi\mathrm i})^a$ with real $a$, we *first* have to correct the imaginary part of the base (the inner exponential) to lie in the interval $(-\pi,\pi]$ by adjusting its exponent by an appropriate multiple of $2\pi\mathrm i$ (which of course does not change the value of the base, as $\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm i}=1$). Obviously the correct adjustment is to subtract $2\pi\mathrm i$ from that exponent, which makes it $0\in (-\pi,\pi]$. Only *now* can we apply the exponential rule, to find that $(\mathrm e^0)^a = \mathrm e^{0a} = 1$.

On the other hand, unless $a$ is an integer, altering the exponent of $\mathrm e^{2\pi a\mathrm i}$ by a multiple of $2\pi\mathrm i$ will never give $0$, and thus the result will not be $1$.

We can also look at my real numbers example in the light of complex numbers.

In polar coordinates, we have $\mathrm i = \mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i}$, where $\pi\in(-\pi,\pi]$.

Now let's first calculate $((-1)^2)^{1/2}$ the “complex way”:

We start by inserting:
$$((-1)^2)^{1/2} = ((\mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i})^2)^{1/2}.$$
Now for the inner exponential, since I already chose the exponent in the right interval, no adjustment is needed, and thus we can just apply the rule:
$$((\mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i})^2)^{1/2} = (\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm i})^2.$$

However now through the multiplication we moved outside the valid interval, therefore *now* we have to adjust the exponent, as before, before applying the exponential rule again:
$$(\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm i})^2 = (\mathrm e^{2\pi\mathrm i-2\pi\mathrm i})^2 = (\mathrm e^0)^2 = \mathrm e^{0\cdot 2}=\mathrm e^0 = 1.$$

So just as before, we find that $((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1$.

On the other hand, we have
$$(-1)^{2(1/2)} = (\mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i})^{2(1/2)} = (\mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i})^1$$
and since now the exponent is already in the right range, we don't have to adjust it, and thus can simply continue:
$$(\mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i})^1 = \mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i\cdot 1} = \mathrm e^{\pi\mathrm i} = -1$$
So as before, we find $(-1)^{2(1/2)} = -1$.

But unlike before, we see also *why* this is the case: It is the case because our definition of the complex exponential function required us to adjust the angle in the first case, but not in the second case. And we defined the exponential function in that way because otherwise we would have ended up with a multivalued “function” which isn't a proper function any more. And the ultimate reason for that is the fact that $x^a=1$ in general has more than one solution.

Comment: Wow, I am totally surprised ! It seems that we've learned is wrong, But what I said applies on your answer, please provide a proof, thanks for mentioning this good point.

Comment: @anaspcpro: I've added a detailed explanation. I'm not sure what proof you expect; a counterexample for a rule *is* a proof that the rule does not hold. Or do you want a proof that the rule holds in the special cases I mentioned?

Comment: That's gonna take a while to read !

Comment: So, you suppose that the reason for all of this is that complex numbers in polar forms must have their angles reduced to be in the interval of the cut, if I got it right you say that $e^{2a \pi i}$ isn't equal to $1$ unless $a$ is an integer which is my second solution. And that the first is wrong because the angle needs to be reduced. Did I get it right ?

Comment: @anaspcpro: Yes, that's right. And the reduction of the angle to the cut is in order to get a single well-defined result.

Comment: But why does it fail even in real numbers ?

Comment: @anaspcpro: Because also in the real numbers, *some* power equations (like $x^2=1$) have several solutions, and while you don't have the problem of discontinuity, you still do have the problem of only being able to select one of them. Since $(-1)^2=1^2$, you cannot have at the same time $((-1)^2)^{1/2}=-1$ and $(1^2)^{1/2}=1$, because both are $1^{1/2}$.

Comment: One last question: are you a mathematician or an amateur ?

Comment: @anaspcpro: I'm physicist, so I'm not a mathematician, but I'm also a bit more than an amateur, since mathematics plays an important role in physics.

Answer (score 3):

The complex exponential is not a one to one function. That is, we can have $e^a=e^b$ with $a\neq b$. Given some such $a$ and $b$ and another number $c$, there's no guarantee that $e^{ac} =e^{bc} $. That is why the rule 
$$(x^{a})^b=x^{ab} $$
does not necessarily hold for complex numbers.

For example, note that $e^{2\pi i} =1$. By the usual rules of real exponentiation, $1^{0.5}=1$. But $e^{0.5(2\pi i)}=e^{\pi i} =-1$. Notice however that we did obtain a square root of $1$, just not the principal square root.

Answer (score 0):

You have used exponential property in a wrong way

$e^{2a\pi i} = \cos {2a\pi} + i \sin{2a \pi}$

Now $e^{2\pi i}=1$

So by your way it becomes that $\cos {2a\pi} + i \sin{2a \pi}=1$ which means that $\cos {2a\pi} = 1$ for any real number $a$

Thus this is not true.You can't use that property in this manner